# How to disable screen mirroring?

Tags: android, video, mirroring, miracast

How to block the app to screen mirroring?
As i check the [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE),

> Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it
>   from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure
>   displays.

The **from being viewed on non-secure displays** is to block screen mirroring? if not, what does it means? And whether we can find some way to prevent the app from the screen mirroring?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The FLAG_SECURE will prevent screenshots of your app and if the screen is recorded it will show a full black screen to prevent sensitive data being displayed for example.

But it does not block screen mirroring / casting unfortunately. There is no way to do it currently with the Android framework.

Comment: Is this correct answer? Are you sure about that FLAG_SECURE prevents screen mirroring?

Comment: Did you read my answer entirely?

Comment: I mean FLAG_SECURE do not prevents screen mirroring ?

Comment: Yes I tested it. It doesn't prevent screen mirroring.

Comment: But in my case, it only shows black screen